# Keras installed but can't import as it says keras module not found

Tags: python, keras, anaconda

```
!pip install Keras
import Keras
print(Keras.__version__)
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
```

after ruuning the above code i got this error encountered as i was trying to solve a classification problem using nlp and deep learning , thats why i tried to install tensorflow and keras. but it constantly throwing me error.

```
 Requirement already satisfied: Keras in c:\users\hind\anaconda3\envs\toxic\lib\site-packages (2.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in c:\users\hind\anaconda3\envs\toxic\lib\site-packages (from Keras) (5.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.9.1 in c:\users\hind\anaconda3\envs\toxic\lib\site-packages (from Keras) (1.19.5)
Requirement already satisfied: h5py in c:\users\hind\anaconda3\envs\toxic\lib\site-packages (from Keras) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.14 in c:\users\hind\anaconda3\envs\toxic\lib\site-packages (from Keras) (1.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: cached-property in c:\users\hind\anaconda3\envs\toxic\lib\site-packages (from h5py->Keras) (1.5.2)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-0a6f7852735b> in <module>
      1 get_ipython().system('pip install Keras')
----> 2 import Keras
      3 print(Keras.__version__)
      4 import tensorflow as tf
      5 print(tf.__version__)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Keras'
```

Comment: Have you restarted kernel after installing keras? If you are running in jupyter notebook

Comment: @Kaveh yes plenty of times

Comment: Have you tried this? `!pip3 install keras`

Comment: @Kaveh issue is not with installing, since requirement already satisfied, it somehow not importing the keras and yes i tried that too

Comment: You have first letter in capital. Use it in lower case. `import keras` not **Keras**.

Comment: The module is called keras, not Keras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this issue these are most common mistakes and their solutions here:

- Both python2 and python3 are installed on your machine, and python2 uses `pip` and python3 uses `pip3`, but you install packages with wrong version. Try using `!pip3 install keras`
- Make sure you have restarted kernel after installing any packages.
- Python is case-sensitive. Make sure you have everything in right case. It is `keras` and `tensorflow`, not Keras or Tensoflow.
- If you have both tensorflow and keras, depend on version, may be some conflicts and you get error while executing `import keras`. Use instead `from tensorflow import keras`.

Comment: the last trick worked. ` from tensorflow import kreas`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
!pip install keras or pip3 install keras

```
import keras
print(keras.__version__)

import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
```

The package name is incorrect in your snippet

Comment: got this error now after doing the above 
AttributeError: module 'keras.utils.generic_utils' has no attribute 'populate_dict_with_module_objects'

Comment: try this: `from tensorflow import keras`

Comment: can you paste the python version, and error stack above in your question?